# Javafx NullPointerException when Playing Sounds

Tags: java, audio, javafx, nullpointerexception

I am working on a Javafx game and have been attempting to implement some sound using the following code:

```
URL laserResource = getClass().getResource("LaserBlast.wav");
AudioClip laserPlayer = new AudioClip(laserResource.toString());
```

This code is instantiated in the main class before any methods. I have a module called JavaFxImages which contains all my resources including my sounds and I have been successfully able to access images for ImageView from the folder through code such as `Image asteroid = new Image("Asteroid.png");`.
However, when I run my game I get a NullPointerException at the line for my audio clip. I have spent the past many hours researching and trying every different way to access this resource.  I've tried many permutations of the URL ("JavaFxImages/LaserBlast.wav", Desktop/JavaFxImages/LaserBlast.wav", etc.), but every time it has the same error.  I'm really at a loss for what is wrong with the code. I would greatly appreciate any help that can be given.
Thanks in advance!

The full error message is given below.

```
Error Message:
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct         Application instance: class sample.Main
    at   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Main.<init>(Main.java:76)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you show us the class implementation? The first few lines. As the error mentioned "Unable to construct Application instance: class sample.Main", that is the constructor error. In other words, your class constructor may have something wrong.

Comment: The path to the .wav file is wrong.

Comment: Let's assume when you run your application you package it as a jar.  If so run "jar tvf <myjar>.jar" where you replace <myjar> with your jar file.  Check that LaserBlast.wav is in whatever jar location that the class you are calling `getClass().getResource("LaserBlast.wav");` is in (I assume that would be `/sample/Main/').  If it is not there you have a packaging issue where your build is not copying the wav file across.  If it is there but in a different location, then you have it in the wrong spot.  If it is not in a jar, you should find it on your file system next to sample/Main.class

Comment: Thank you to all who answered, you have solved the problem for me.  I created a new directory called JavaFxSounds and put it in /src/sample instead of simply inside my project.  I am still a little confused as to how I can access image resources from a directory outside of my main class but not sound files, but at least the sound is working! Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Your error mostly happens on Itellij IDEA - Javafx Project

Instead of:

```
URL laserResource = getClass().getResource("LaserBlast.wav");
AudioClip laserPlayer = new AudioClip(laserResource.toString());
```

Use:

```
//By default your Package_NAME is: sample
File laserResource = new File("src/Package_NAME/LaserBlast.wav");
AudioClip laserPlayer = new AudioClip(laserResource.toURI().toString());
```

Comment: Most certainly not: resource lookup should happen from the package path, not the file path (and absolutely _not_ a file path related to the source which is not available at runtime